# Openmodelica error: "The tearing heuristic was not able to avoid discrete iteration variables..."

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I'm developing a simulation of a swarm of drones. I made a function for checking area in front of drones, but when i'm trying to use it it displays this error:

```
"The tearing heuristic was not able to avoid discrete iteration variables because otherwise the system could not have been torn".
```

This is the function:

```
function seeNearObject "Restituisce una lista contenente tutti gli oggetti rilevati dal sistema video del drone"
    
    InputReal x;
    InputReal y;
    InputReal z;

    InputReal x2[K.N];
    InputReal y2[K.N];
    InputReal z2[K.N];

    InputReal destX;
    InputReal destY; 
    InputReal destZ; 

    InputReal intrX[K.nIntr];
    InputReal intrY[K.nIntr];
    InputReal intrZ[K.nIntr];

    InputReal missX[K.nRocket];
    InputReal missY[K.nRocket];
    InputReal missZ[K.nRocket];

    InputReal statX[K.nStatObs];
    InputReal statY[K.nStatObs];
    InputReal statZ[K.nStatObs];

    OutputBool outneighbours[K.N];
    OutputBool outnearIntr[K.nIntr];
    OutputBool outnearMissile[K.nRocket];
    OutputBool outnearStatObs[K.nStatObs];

    protected
        Real viewField[3];

algorithm
    
    //Imposto i limiti del campo visivo. Data la direzione del drone, ogni asse avrà il suo limite.
    // viewField := findViewField(x,y,z, destX,destY,destZ);
    viewField := zeros(3);

    for j in 1:K.N loop
        outneighbours[j] := false;
        if((x2[j] >= x and x2[j] <= viewField[1]) or (x2[j] <= x and x2[j] >= viewField[1])) then
            if((y2[j] >= y and y2[j] <= viewField[2]) or (y2[j] <= y and y2[j] >= viewField[2])) then
                if((z2[j] >= z and z2[j] <= viewField[3]) or (z2[j] <= z and z2[j] >= viewField[3])) then
                    outneighbours[j] := true;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end for;

    for j in 1:K.nIntr loop
        outnearIntr[j] := false;
        if((intrX[j] >= x and intrX[j] <= viewField[1]) or (intrX[j] <= x and intrX[j] >= viewField[1])) then
            if((intrY[j] >= y and intrY[j] <= viewField[2]) or (intrY[j] <= y and intrY[j] >= viewField[2])) then
                if((intrZ[j] >= z and intrZ[j] <= viewField[3]) or (intrZ[j] <= z and intrZ[j] >= viewField[3])) then
                    outnearIntr[j] := true;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end for; 

    for j in 1:K.nRocket loop
        outnearMissile[j] := false;
        if((missX[j] >= x and missX[j] <= viewField[1]) or (missX[j] <= x and missX[j] >= viewField[1])) then
            if((missY[j] >= y and missY[j] <= viewField[2]) or (missY[j] <= y and missY[j] >= viewField[2])) then
                if((missZ[j] >= z and missZ[j] <= viewField[3]) or (missZ[j] <= z and missZ[j] >= viewField[3])) then
                    outnearMissile[j] := true;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end for; 

    for j in 1:K.nStatObs loop
        outnearStatObs[j] := false;
        if((statX[j] >= x and statX[j] <= viewField[1]) or (statX[j] <= x and statX[j] >= viewField[1])) then
            if((statY[j] >= y and statY[j] <= viewField[2]) or (statY[j] <= y and statY[j] >= viewField[2])) then
                if((statZ[j] >= z and statZ[j] <= viewField[3]) or (statZ[j] <= z and statZ[j] >= viewField[3])) then
                    outnearStatObs[j] := true;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end for; 

end seeNearObject;
```

All the inputs are point in a 3D space, and I have a similar function (written better than this) but it works clearly. Is there any error?

Answer (score 0):

you probably solved this, but as far as I can see there are two issues with the code that may be causing the error.

(1)  I don't see any initial condition in the algorithm. In OpenModelica you should always have a

```
when initial() then [...] end when;
```

in which you specify the starting values of each parameter (except for the ones in Input).

(2)  When reading a status related variable `var` you should always use the `pre(var)` call, to read the last value of `var`, not the current. That is because OpenModelica uses algebraic formulas to solve the system and if your model has loops (all big models do) it may lead to this very issue in which the algebraic formula is inconsistent.

Like so

```
x := x + 2
```

It should always be something like

```
x := pre(x) + 2
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: First of all, thanks for having spent your time answer my question. 
I remade it because it wasn't a good function (Just look at it, it's obvious), but right now i have some doubt:
(1) i'm inside a function, are you sure i need to use when initial() ? 
(2) the pre() operator it's not only used in equations?